# Simple question of maximum value a part can have?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, maximum-principle

We have to partition n chocolates among m children.
Children will be happy if max and min a child has got is less than 2.
What is the max a child can get??

For n=6 m=3 ,the partition will be 2 2 2
Maximum a child can get is 2

For n=7 m=3 ,the partition will be 2 3 2
Maximum a child can get is 3

How to get maximum without knowing the partition?

Comment: yes the chocolates should be split on the criteria that maximum - minimum <2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by giving each child $\left\lfloor\frac{n}m\right\rfloor$ pieces; if there are any left over, give $n-m\left\lfloor\frac{n}m\right\rfloor$ of the children one more piece each. This is the only way to keep the difference between the minimum and maximum less than $2$. The maximum will then be $\left\lceil\frac{n}m\right\rceil$.

If the floor and ceiling functions are unfamiliar, let $n=mq+r$, where $0\le r<m$. If $r=0$, each child gets $q$ chocolates. (Giving any child more than that forces you to give some child fewer than $q$, making the difference between maximum and minimum greater than $1$.) If $r>0$, give $r$ children one more chocolate each; the maximum will then be $q+1$ and the minimum $q$.

Comment: sir max will be n-m[n/m]+[n/m] if there if left over,
if not then [n/m]
an i right?

Comment: @Vidyut: It will be $\frac{n}m$ if $n$ is a multiple of $m$, and it will be $\left\lfloor\frac{n}m\right\rfloor+1$ if there is a remainder.

Comment: thank you sir it was very helpful

Comment: @Vidyut: You’re welcome.

Comment: @user2307487: Because the answer should certainly contain at least a general indication of **why** the maximum is $\left\lceil\frac{n}m\right\rceil$, not just the bare statement that that **is** the maximum.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My mistake, for some reason I am seeing `\left \lceil \frac{n}{m} \right \rceil` rendered as $\left |\frac{n}{m} \right |$ so I thought you had the absolute value function instead of the ceiling function. But when I looked at the raw text of your post I saw the correct latex for the ceiling function. I do wonder though if I am the only one with this rendering problem?

Comment: @user2307487: No, you’re not: I also sometimes have it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that if you erase the '\left' and '\right' then it will render correctly.

Comment: @Andrew: Not really: the hooks at the top will be visible, but the symbols as a whole will be too short.